# Integer type of a bitfield

Tags: c, bit-fields

Is the integer type of a bitfield important, or is it basically a throwaway, for example:

```
struct font {
    int bold : 1;
    int italics : 2;
    int underline : 1;
};
```

vs.

```
struct font {
    unsigned int bold : 1;
    unsigned int italics : 2;
    unsigned int underline : 1;
};
```

vs.

```
struct font {
    char bold : 1;
    char italics : 2;
    char underline : 1;
};
```

Does a different integer type 'do' anything here, or is it basically a placeholder?

Comment: Well, `int bold : 1;` can be only `-1` or `0`, whereas `unsigned int bold : 1;` can be `1` or `0`.

Comment: @KamilCuk when I use an int field the compiler doesn't complain if I set `bold=1`, but it does if I set `bold=2`.

Comment: Nor compiler complains when you do `char a = 1000;`, but `char` can (typically ;) only hold `-128` to `127`... The value is _converted_ to the range of the destination type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whether a bit-field uses a signed or unsigned type makes a different in the values it can hold.  In your first example `bold` can hold the values 0 or -1, while in your second example `bold` can hold the values 0 and 1.

The C standard specifically allows `int`, `unsigned int`, or `_Bool` as the type for a bit-field, with support for other types being implementation defined.  Most implementations will allow any integer type for a bit-field.

For those that do, the type specifies the size of the "bucket" the bit-field lives in, so it can affect the size of the struct.  On my machine under gcc, the first two structs have size 4 while the third has size 1.

Comment: one question for clarification. This sentence: "The C standard specifically allows int, unsigned int, or _Bool" -- do you mean "The C standard **for a bit field** ... ?

Comment: @David542 Yes.  Updated.